# NodeJS + Mongoose: saving a model and get back the ID to aggregate in another model

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I need your help. Here are the premises:

I've got a catalog of products with 3 different type of categories. To illustrate with a simple example I've got this:

> The "**mains**":
>
> - Fruits & Vegetables
> - Meat
> - Fish
>
> "**Submains**":
>
> from the *main* "**Fruits & Vegetables**" I've got:
>
> - Fruit
> - Vegetables
>
> and then a bunch of "**Subcategories**":
>
> - Inside the *main* "**meat**": beef, pork, poultry
> - Inside the *main* "**fish**": tuna, salmon
> - Inside the *submain* "**Fruit**": banana, watermelon
> - Inside the *submain* "**Vegetables**": carrots, peas

So I created a 3 steps function that first takes the "**Subcategories**" and save them into a specific collection then aggregates the '_id' and *main* or *submain* it corresponds to into an Array. Here's a simplification of the code:

```
  const categories = {
    subMainCats: [{name: "fruit", ref: "4", family: "1"}, {name: "vegetables", ref: "5", family: "1"}],
    mainCats: [{name: "Fruits & Vegetables", ref: "1"}, {name: "meat", ref: "2"}, {name: "fish", ref: "3"}],
    subCats: [{name: "beef", fam: "2"}, {name: "pork", fam: "2"}, {name: "poultry", fam: "2"}, {name: "tuna", fam: "3"}, {name: "salmon", fam: "3"}, {name: "pork", fam: "5"}, {name: "peas", fam: "5"}, {name: "banana", fam: "4"}, {name: "watermelon", fam: "4"}]
  };

async function orderingDb(categories) {
  var subMains = categories.subMainCats;
  var mains = categories.mainCats;
  var subCats = categories.subCats;

  // Variables to recover info from elements that were added to db:
  var addedSubCats = [];
  var addedSubMains = [];

// Step 1: saving the subcats
await subCats.forEach(async (subCat, index) =>{
      const name =subCat.name;
      const fam = subCat.fam;

      // Creating the mongoose model object
      const subcat = new Subcategory({
        name: name,
        fam: main
      });

      // Saving to the db and adding the _id to the array
      await subcat.save().then(res => {
        console.log('saving subcat!');
        addedSubCats.push({
          main: main,
          _id: res._id
        });
      }).catch(err => console.log('ERROR: trying to save a subcat to mongo -- ', err));
  });

// Step 2: Adding the subcats and saving the submains
await subMains.forEach(async (subMain, index) => {
      const name = subMain.name;
      const fam = subMain.family;
      var subCats = [];

      // adding the subcats to the array
      addedSubCats.forEach((addedSubCat, index) =>{
        if(addedSubCat.main === subMain.category.subFamily) {
          subCats.push(addedSubCat._id);
          addedSubCats.splice(index);
        }
      });

      // Creating mongoose model object:
      const submain = new Submaincategory({
        name: name,
        subCats: subCats,
        main: main
      });

      // Saving and adding the _ids: 
      await submain.save().then(res => {
        console.log('saving submain');
        addedSubMains.push({
          main: main,
          _id: res._id
        })
      }).catch(err => console.log('ERROR: trying to save a Submain -- ', err ));
  });

 // ... FINALLY I'VE GOT THE SAME LOGIC FOR STEP 3 FOR THE MAINS.

}
```

**Here's my problem though: *The MODEL.save()* function that my async function should wait for gets executed at the very end of the function. Meanning that my *addedSubCats* and *addedSubMains* arrays are empty when the rest of the function gets executed...**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the problem is to create the _id before saving the model:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
const _id = new ObjectID();
const fruit = new Fruit({_id, ...fruitBody})
fruit.save(cb);

// in this manner you will know in advance the _ids of the objects you will create
// so you can populate the array of _ids to be aggregated later
```